# Exporting STL std::vector functionality trough DLL

Tags: c++

I have written a piece of code which uses C++ STL (std::vector) internally to store some info and then provide it trough C like functions that will be exported later in Windows DLL. I am wondering if this way will be correct and stable. I will be appreciate if someone with some experience in this field could confirm me that it is ok or point me to the problems. 
This is just a draft example and all error handling functionality will be added later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef struct _c_vector_wrapper_config
{
    size_t currentPosition = -1;
    // for std::string
    std::vector<std::string> *vPointer = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator vIterator;

    // for C null terminated string 
    // we support 2 type of vectors to have ability to work with C like strings from other than C++
    // languages 
    // Also we allocate memory for this string using C runtime malloc and at the end we can easily free 
    // this memory to avoid memory leaks.

    // Why we use also std::vector<std::string> ? Because STL string operation is more simple and safe
    // and we need C like strings only to export them from DLL
    std::vector<char*> *vPointerChar = nullptr;
    std::vector<char*>::iterator vIteratorChar;

} c_vector_wrapper_config;



c_vector_wrapper_config *vector_wrapper_config = new c_vector_wrapper_config();

// c_vector_wrapper_config *vector_wrapper_config = new c_vector_wrapper_config();



void create_vector();
void delete_vector();
void add_value(std::string value);
char* get_value();


int main(void)
{

    create_vector();

    add_value("test1");
    add_value("test2");
    add_value("test3");

    std::cout << get_value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_value() << std::endl;

    delete_vector();

    return 0;
}

void create_vector()
{
    if (vector_wrapper_config->vPointer == nullptr)
    {
        vector_wrapper_config->vPointer = new std::vector<std::string>();
        vector_wrapper_config->vPointerChar = new std::vector<char*>();
    }

}

void add_value(std::string value)
{
    vector_wrapper_config->vPointer->push_back(value);

    std::size_t str_length = value.size();
    char *c_string = static_cast<char*>(malloc(str_length +1));
    value.copy(c_string, str_length, 0);
    c_string[str_length] = '\0';

    vector_wrapper_config->vPointerChar->push_back(c_string);
}

char* get_value()
{
    vector_wrapper_config->currentPosition++;
    char* current_value =  (*vector_wrapper_config->vPointerChar)[vector_wrapper_config->currentPosition];

    return current_value;
}

void delete_vector()
{
    delete vector_wrapper_config->vPointer;

    // free memory allocated previously for C like strings
    for (std::vector<char*>::iterator it = vector_wrapper_config->vPointerChar->begin(); it != vector_wrapper_config->vPointerChar->end(); ++it)
    {
        free(*it);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exporting C-style wrappers is fine. Using `std::string` in the signature of those wrappers is not (for the same reason you are hiding `std::vector` behind wrappers in the first place).

Comment: `delete_vector` leaks `vPointerChar`

Comment: `vPointer` seems redundant - you add elements to it, but never read anything from it.

Comment: I agree with you Igor, thanks